# Мультиязычный контент в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Как правильно реализовать мультиязычность контента, который будет добавляться через админку в yii2? Мультиязычность статичных страниц сделал с помощью модуля `klisl/yii2-languages`.

Планирую сделать мультиязычность через создание двух таблиц для одной сущности, на примере `news`:

Таблица `news` (поля не требующие перевода):

`| id | code | date | image |`

Таблица `news_content` (поля требующие перевода):

`| id | parent_id | title | description | body | location | lang |`

Т.е. связка будет по `news.id -> news_content.parent_id`

Если с выводом всё понятно, то каким образом правильно на уровне админки это делать? Как можно связать две модели, чтобы поля генерировались в зависимости от количества языков? И каким образом записывать в БД, с моделью `News` проблем нет, но для `NewsContent` мы создаём (если 2 языка) 2 объекта, каждый раз отлавливать в контроллере $_POST и сохранять в БД в цикле?

> UPDATE

Реализовал как и советовали в комментариях

В модели `News.php` добавил `public $contents;`

В `_form.php` записываем в `$contents`:

```
<div class="tabs-contents">
        <?
            $langs = \Yii::$app->getModule('languages')->languages;
            foreach ($langs as $title_lang => $key){
                echo '<div class="tab-content">';
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][title]')->textInput()->label('title (' . $key . ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][description]')->textInput()->label('description (' . $key . ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][body]')->textInput()->label('body (' . $key. ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][location]')->textInput()->label('location (' . $key. ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][id]')->hiddenInput()->label(false);
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

В контроллере `NewsController.php`:

Создание

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new News();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей
            $NewsContents = Yii::$app->request->post()["News"]["contents"];
            foreach ($NewsContents as $lang => $content){
                $NewsContent = new NewsContent();
                $NewsContent->load(["NewsContent" => $content]);
                $NewsContent->lang = $lang;
                $NewsContent->news_id = $model->id;
                $NewsContent->save();
            }
            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

Обновление

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        //Примешиваем контент к выборке
        $contents = NewsContent::find()->where(['news_id' => $id])->asArray()->all();
        $contents = ArrayHelper::index($contents, 'lang');
        $model->contents = $contents;
        //Примешиваем контент к выборке
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей
            $NewsContents = Yii::$app->request->post()["News"]["contents"];
            foreach ($NewsContents as $lang => $content){

                if(!$content["id"]){ $NewsContent = new NewsContent(); }
                else{ $NewsContent = NewsContent::find()->where(['id' => $content['id']])->one(); }

                $NewsContent->load(["NewsContent" => $content]);
                $NewsContent->lang = $lang;
                $NewsContent->news_id = $model->id;
                $NewsContent->save();
            }
            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Удаление

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        //Удаление контента вместе с новостью
        NewsContent::deleteAll(['news_id' => $id]);

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Comment: Выводить один язык под другим, затем на js скрыть все поля, кроме текущего языка. Сохранять все вместе в цикле по языкам.

Comment: Я так понимаю поля должны быть ` $form->field($content, 'title_en')->textInput();` но `yii2` ругается что не знает такого поля `title_en`, заранее добавить можно мнимые поля, но я не знаю сколько языков будет и какие они будут, в динамическом режиме можно их задать?

Comment: Про yii вам ничего не могу сказать. Поищите компоненты под это дело.

Comment: Да уже искал, везде упор делают на вывод в front'е, даже взять https://klisl.com/multilingual_BD.html ни слова о наполнении в админ панели.

Comment: Вы можете заранее получить список языков, а затем в цикле подставлять префикс языка (ru, en, de), генерируя уникальные языковые поля. По идее так.